# Arduino Uno alarm interrupt

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, rtc

I am trying to create a temperature-humidity monitor using Arduino and I want to power it using a battery. So, power efficiency is of interest. I am trying to put the Arduino to sleep for x-time (10sec for testing now). I am using a DS3231 alarm as an interrupt on pin 2 to wake-up. I am using the [tutorial here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Sleep-and-Wakeup-Test-With-DS3231-RTC/) along with its associated [RTClibExtended](https://github.com/FabioCuomo/FabioCuomo-DS3231/blob/master/examples/wakeup_alarm/wakeup_alarm.ino) library. Here is the code I am using:

```
#include "DHT.h"
#include <RTClibExtended.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LowPower.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>      // library for interrupts handling
#include <avr/sleep.h>          // library for sleep
#include <avr/power.h>          // library for power control


#define DHTPIN 7     // what pin we're connected to
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)
#define wakePin 2    //use interrupt 0 (pin 2) and run function wakeUp when pin 2 gets LOW


RTC_DS3231 rtc;
char daysOfTheWeek[7][12] = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
int interval_sec=10; //An alarm every 10 sec
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup () {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  delay(3000); // wait for console opening

  /**RTC**/
  if (! rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while (1);
  }
  rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));

  /**INTERRUPT**/
  //Set pin D2 as INPUT for accepting the interrupt signal from DS3231
  pinMode(wakePin, INPUT);
  Wire.begin();
  //clear any pending alarms
  rtc.armAlarm(1, false);
  rtc.clearAlarm(1);
  rtc.alarmInterrupt(1, false);
  rtc.armAlarm(2, false);
  rtc.clearAlarm(2);
  rtc.alarmInterrupt(2, false);

  //Set SQW pin to OFF (in my case it was set by default to 1Hz)
  //The output of the DS3231 INT pin is connected to this pin
  //It must be connected to arduino D2 pin for wake-up
  rtc.writeSqwPinMode(DS3231_OFF);

  Serial.println("Initialisation complete.");
  delay(100); //Allow for serial print to complete.
}

void loop () {
    DateTime now = rtc.now();

    Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
    Serial.print('/');
    Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
    Serial.print(" (");
    Serial.print(daysOfTheWeek[now.dayOfTheWeek()]);
    Serial.print(") ");
    Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    Serial.print(':');
    Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
    Serial.println();

    /**Temperature and Humidity**/
    // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
    // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
    float h = dht.readHumidity();
    // Read temperature as Celsius
    float t = dht.readTemperature();
    // Read temperature as Fahrenheit
    //float f = dht.readTemperature(true);

    // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
    //if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f)) {
    if (isnan(h) || isnan(t)) {
      Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor!");
      return;
    }


    Serial.print("Humidity: ");
    Serial.print(h);
    Serial.print(" %\t");
    Serial.print("Temperature: ");
    Serial.print(t);
    Serial.println(" *C\t");

    delay(3000); // wait for console

    /**INTURRUPT**/
    DateTime nextAlarm = now + TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);
    Serial.print("Alarm at:");
    Serial.println(nextAlarm.hour());
    Serial.println(nextAlarm.minute());
    Serial.println(nextAlarm.second());
    rtc.setAlarm(ALM1_MATCH_HOURS, nextAlarm.minute(), nextAlarm.hour(), nextAlarm.second());   //set your wake-up time here
    rtc.alarmInterrupt(1, true);
    delay(3000); // wait for console
    attachInterrupt(0, wakeUp, LOW);       //use interrupt 0 (pin 2) and run function wakeUp when pin 2 gets LOW    
    LowPower.powerDown(SLEEP_FOREVER, ADC_OFF, BOD_OFF);   //arduino enters sleep mode here
    detachInterrupt(0);                                    //execution resumes from here after wake-up
    //When exiting the sleep mode we clear the alarm
    rtc.armAlarm(1, false);
    rtc.clearAlarm(1);
    rtc.alarmInterrupt(1, false);

    Serial.println();
    delay(3000);
}

void wakeUp()        // here the interrupt is handled after wakeup
{
}
```

The Arduino is going to sleep as expected, but not waking up. Where am I going wrong?

Here is the output:

> Initialisation complete. 2017/6/7 (Wednesday) 12:42:49 Humidity: 36.90
>   % Temperature: 25.60 *C
>   Alarm at:12
>   42
>   59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying for a few hours, I was able to figure it out.

The change required is:

```
rtc.setAlarm(ALM1_MATCH_HOURS, nextAlarm.second(), nextAlarm.minute(), nextAlarm.hour (), 1);   //set wake-up time here
```

So, in the original code, the order of arguments as well as the number of arguments passed to *rtc.setAlarm()* was wrong. Even though we are not interested in the "day" part (last argument) for setting the alarm, it requires a value. Using *ALM1_MATCH_HOURS* ensures that we match the alarm time to seconds, minutes, and hours ignoring the day part.

**Improvement**

Instead of hardcoding the alarm interval, the global variable called *interval_sec* can be set at the top and used to set the alarm time:

```
DateTime nextAlarm = now + TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, interval_sec);
```

Answer (score 0):

In RTClibExtended.h it is important to always include all arguments: seconds, minutes, hours, daydate. If 0 value is used then this means "always" for that argument.

**Example:**

```
RTC.setAlarm(ALM1_MATCH_SECONDS, 30, 00, 0, 0); // activate every minute at 30 seconds
RTC.setAlarm(ALM2_MATCH_MINUTES, 0, 01, 0, 0); // activate every hour at 01 minutes
RTC.setAlarm(ALM1_MATCH_HOURS, 33, 18, 0); // activate every day at 18:33
```

(note: this example is copied from RTClibExtended.h examples, author does not adhere to his own rule to include seconds, even in ALM2. But it works).
Any suggestions or corrections are welcomed!